# How to give negative log10 distribution to Python probplot function for qq-plotting p-values?

Tags: python, statistics, scipy.stats

I want to translate the following code from R to Python using `scipy.stats.probplot`.

```
qqplot(-log10(ppoints(1000)), -log10(p_value))
```

This is Q-Q plot of p-values compared to uniform distribution with a minus log scale. I am after something like the following. (I know that there are other libraries that achieve this, but I am looking for the answer for `probplot`.)

```
probplot(-np.log10(p_values_data), dist="uniform", sparams=(0, 1), plot=plt)
```

This does not work correctly because, the x-axis is uniform. Here, `plt` is due to `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. I found the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55225458/scipy-stats-probplot-to-generate-qqplot-using-a-custom-distribution), among others, but I did not find anything on modifying the `dist` parameter to accommodate `-log10(uniform)`.

How can I get this plot using `probplot`?

**Here is a revision of the problem description.**

Here is the data generation.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import chi2,probplot
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def compute_p_with_chi2(x,y):
    model = ols('y ~ x', data=dict(y=y, x=x)).fit()
    t_stat = model.tvalues['x']
    p_value = 1-chi2.cdf(t_stat**2, 1)
    return p_value

def compute_pvalues(X_data,p_data):
  p_values = []
  for col in X_data.T:
      p_value = compute_p_with_chi2(col,p_data)
      p_values.append(p_value)
  return p_values

n = 100
p = 1000
X = np.random.binomial(2, 0.4, size=(n, p))
y = np.random.normal(size=n)

p_values = compute_pvalues(X,y)
```

Doing a histogram of the p-values, I get a uniform distribution as expected.

```
plt.hist(p_values)
```

However, plotting the Q-Q using the `probplot`, I do not get two overlapping diagonals. Here is what I get.

[image]

```
probplot(-np.log10(p_values), dist="uniform", sparams=(0, 1), plot=plt)
```

I am including the desired output from R with the (first) code above.

[image]

My feeling is that this is something very simple, but I am somehow missing it.

Answer (score 0):

you can manually transform the data in order to compare them to a uniform distribution:

```
transformed_data = -np.log10(p_values_data)

expected_quantiles = stats.uniform.ppf(np.linspace(0.001, 0.999, len(transformed_data)))
```

and then the command you've already provided

Comment: No, unfortunately, this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The `dist` parameter accepts an object that works like a probability distribution; more specifically, it must have a `ppf` method. If want to compare your data against the log-uniform distribution (the distribution of a random variable whose logarithm is uniformly distributed), you would do:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import probplot
from scipy import stats

a, b = 1e-6, 1
p_values_data = np.logspace(-6, 0, 100)
probplot(p_values_data, dist=stats.loguniform, sparams=(a, b), plot=plt)
```

[image]

If you want your x-axis to be log-spaced, you would add:

```py
plt.gca().set_xscale('log')
```

[image]

If this doesn't answer your question, please include in your question a minimal reproducible example - in this case, the data and an example of the plot you are trying to produce.

Comment: Thank you. The first parameter needs to be `-np.log10(p_values_data)`, not p_values. If I replace "uniform" in your solution, it works better for the p_values_data you suggest. Try this instead: `p_values_data = -np.log10(np.linspace(0, 1, 1000))`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it is required for the first parameter to be:

```py
-np.log10(p_values_data)
```

where `p_values_data` are some values distributed between `0` and `1`, and the comparison is to be made against the uniform distribution. This is equivalent to my previous answer, but it's a different way of visualizing it.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import probplot

a, b = 1e-6, 1
p_values_data = np.logspace(-6, 0, 1000)
probplot(-np.log10(p_values_data), dist="uniform", sparams=(0, 6), plot=plt)
# plt.gca().set_xscale('log')  # if desired for some reason
```

[image]

The main difference from the user's original code is that the parameters passed to the uniform distribution should reflect the range of the distribution - the lower limit can be `0`, but in that case the upper limit needs to be at least `-log10(np.min(p_values_data))`. If you choose to change the lower limit, note that [SciPy's uniform distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.uniform.html) is parameterized by the left endpoint and the scale (difference between endpoints), not the left and right endpoints separately.

If one of the `p_values_data` is exactly `0`, then `-log10(0)` is infinite. You would need to specify what you want to happen in that case.

Again, if this doesn't answer your question, please include in your question a minimal reproducible example - in this case, the data and an example of the plot you are trying to produce.